# Devolver upload de imagem em index.php

Tags: php, html, upload

Fiz o upload de uma imagem e ao clicar em "enviar" quero que me mostre
a imagem na pagina 'index.php'.Apresentando imagem no browser

Código:

```
<html>
  <body> 
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
      Selecione : <input name="arquivo" type="file"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/> 
    </form>

    <?php

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $aki = $_POST['arquivo']; 
        if (empty($aki)) {
             echo "introduza de novo";
        } else {
             echo $aki;
        }
    }

    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Resultado: mostra o nome do ficheiro e não carrega a imagem como pretendido.

Comment: Primeiro, adicione `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ao elemento `form`. Segundo, seu arquivo estará disponível em `$_FILES["arquivo"]`, não em `$_POST`. Terceiro, tente ler este [material](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php), acredito que vai te ajudar.

Comment: Mostrar na index, tudo bem, porém que página é essa do upload? e em que diretório está?

Comment: a imagem ta no ambiente de trabalho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `$_POST` não obtem o arquivo, o correto é `$_FILES` e o form deve ter `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, antes de sair fazendo qualquer coisa recomendo que comece a estudar pela documentação https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php.

Um exemplo básico deve ser mais ou menos assim:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Selecione : <input name="arquivo" type="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>

    <?php
    //Salva a foto com nome aleatório dentro da pasta
    $pasta = 'pasta-upload';

    $arq = $pasta . '/' . uniqid(rand(), true);

    $image = false;

    if (!chmod($pasta, 0755)) {
        echo 'Erro ao mudar as permissões';
    } else if (isset($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'])) {
        if ($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            echo 'Erro no upload';
        } else {
            $tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

            $image = getimagesize($tmp);

            $ext = str_replace(array('image/', 'x-'), '', $image['mime']);

            $arq .= '.' . $ext;

            if (!$image) {
                echo 'Formato invalido';
            } else if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp, $arq)) {
                echo 'Erro ao mover o arquivo';
            } else {
                echo '<img src="', $arq, '">';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

- No exemplo use uma pasta chamada `pasta-upload`, ela deve estar na mesma pasta que o index.php
- O `action=""` esta vazio, isto faz com que o upload seja enviado para mesma página

Comment: devolve isto Warning: move_uploaded_file(pasta-upload/586881221590d3f3e4fb356.72248506.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tm/index.php on line 27

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpxee8go' to 'pasta-upload/586881221590d3f3e4fb356.72248506.jpeg' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tm/index.php on line 27
Erro ao mover o arquivo

Comment: quando eu abro o navegador eu coloco o endereço http://127.0.0.1/tm/ e aparece o formulário  e sempre o warning Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tm/index.php on line 16
Erro ao mudar as permissões

Comment: if (!chmod($pasta, 0755))  é so alterar o coding aki por  if (!is_writable($pasta))