# Erro de permissões ao tentar enviar um arquivo com PHP

Tags: php, upload, permissões

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Selecione : <input name="arquivo" type="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>

    <?php
    //Salva a foto com nome aleatório dentro da pasta
    $pasta = 'pasta-upload';

    $arq = $pasta . '/' . uniqid(rand(), true);

    $image = false;

    if (!chmod($pasta, 0755)) {
        echo 'Erro ao mudar as permissões';
    } else if (isset($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'])) {
        if ($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            echo 'Erro no upload';
        } else {
            $tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

            $image = getimagesize($tmp);

            $ext = str_replace(array('image/', 'x-'), '', $image['mime']);

            $arq .= '.' . $ext;

            if (!$image) {
                echo 'Formato invalido';
            } else if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp, $arq)) {
                echo 'Erro ao mover o arquivo';
            } else {
                echo '<img src="', $arq, '">';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Devolve o seguinte

> Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tm/index.php on line 16
>   Erro ao mudar as permissões.

Já tentei ir ao terminal e executar o comandos

```
sudo chmod 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tm/pasta-upload   
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tm/
sudo chmod 755 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tm/pasta-upload
```

Estou a usar o XAMPP.

Comment: O erro persiste porque, mesmo que tenha alterado as permissões do diretório, você está tentando alterar novamente no código (e é o código que não tem permissões de fazer esta alteração). Tente substituir a parte do código `if (!chmod($pasta, 0755))` por `if (!is_writable($pasta))`.

Comment: funcionou obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para referências, o código em questão foi desenvolvido nesta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202754/devolver-upload-de-imagem-em-index-php).

O que acontece é que no código, mais precisamente na linha `!chmod($pasta, 0755)`, você está tentando alterar as permissões do diretório definido `$pasta`, de forma a garantir que o mesmo possa ser gravado. O erro é gerado porque o PHP não possui permissões necessárias para fazer esta alteração. Por isso foi necessário que você executasse este comando manualmente:

```
sudo chmod 755 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tm/pasta-upload
```

Feito isso, você já definiu a permissão de escrita no diretório, então no código você não precisa fazê-lo novamente, mas o que precisa é garantir que o diretório possua esta permissão e isso é feito com a função `is_writable`. Desta forma, seu código ficaria:

```
...

if (!is_writable($pasta)) {
    echo 'O diretório não possui permissão de escrita.';
} else if (isset($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'])) {
    if ($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo 'Erro no upload';
    } else {
        $tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

        $image = getimagesize($tmp);

        $ext = str_replace(array('image/', 'x-'), '', $image['mime']);

        $arq .= '.' . $ext;

        if (!$image) {
            echo 'Formato invalido';
        } else if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp, $arq)) {
            echo 'Erro ao mover o arquivo';
        } else {
            echo '<img src="', $arq, '">';
        }
    }
}

...
```

Desta forma, o envio do arquivo somente ocorre quando o diretório possui as permissões necessárias.

Comment: Então o PHP não possui permissão porque porque o usuário proprietário não é o mesmo, se eu não me engano o usuário seria o `www-data`, eu ia comentar isto na resposta, mas eu estava para testar primeiro no Mac do trabalho.